# Reference request: $p$-adic Lie extension

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm learning $p$-adic Hodge theory recently, and I have met some conclusions that need knowledge of $p$-adic Lie extension. But I have never learnt anything about it. Could you share some references on this topic? Detailed materials and concise ones are all welcome.

Besides, could you point a way that I can follow to have a knowledgement of important conclusions immediately (without a good knowledge of details)?

Appreciate ahead!

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106270) by Venjakob has some details and references, but also discussed Iwasawa theory for it. It is the "PhD-thesis" of him.